# How to search for a pattern with sed and replace another substring on that line

Tags: sed, syntax

I need to find all lines in my data file that contain NO_ID and then replace the string "confirmed" by "to be confirmed".

I tried this:

```
sed '/NO_ID/, s/confirmed/to be confirmed/' stats.txt
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma.  The initial regular expression acts as the "address" for the subsequent `s` command (the space shown here between the address and the command is optional):

```bash
sed '/NO_ID/ s/confirmed/to be confirmed/' stats.txt
```

This could be further shortened if we replace the word `confirmed` with the thing matched by the regular expression in the `s` command:

```bash
sed '/NO_ID/ s/confirmed/to be &/' stats.txt
```

If you need to ensure that lines containing `to be confirmed` are not modified:

```bash
sed '/NO_ID/ { /to be confirmed/!s/confirmed/to be &/; }' stats.txt
```

or,

```bash
sed -e '/to be confirmed/b' -e '/NO_ID/ s/confirmed/to be &/' stats.txt
```

Here, the first command first detects lines containing `NO_ID` and applies the substitution to these unless the line also contains `to be confirmed`. The second command detects and skips lines containing `to be confirmed` (the `b` instruction jumps to the end of the script, causing the line not to be further modified but printed). Lines not containing `to be confirmed` undergo the same modification as in the original command.

Comment: Excellent additional tip, thanks.

Comment: note that this will not only change "confirmed" to "to be confirmed", it will also change any existing NO_ID lines with "to be confirmed" to "to be to be confirmed".   Try `perl -pe 's/(?<!to be )confirmed/to be $&/ if /NO_ID/'` (this uses a negative look-behind so that it only changes "confirmed" when it isn't preceded by "to be " - see `man perlre` and search for "Lookaround Assertions" ... *"Lookaround assertions are zero-width patterns which match a specific pattern without including it in $&."*)

Comment: BTW, there's only one version of "sed" that I know of which supports lookaround assertions, and that's [super sed](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/ssed/) AKA `ssed` which uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library - [PCRE](https://pcre.org/).   With ssed, you could do: `ssed '/NO_ID/ s/(?<!to be )confirmed/to be &/'`.   [ssed is packaged for debian](https://packages.debian.org/stable/utils/ssed) and probably other distros...but I can't really see any compelling reason to use ssed instead of perl.

Comment: @cas This is true. We have to trust that the user knows about their data and what they want to do with it. The main point with the question was to get help with the syntax of the `sed` command though.

Comment: @cas In `sed`, the way to solve this is to use `/NO_ID/ { /to be confirmed/! s/confirmed/to be &/; }`.  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: kind of, but it isn't the same as the negative look-behind assertion.  It's probably good enough in this case but will only avoid changing "confirmed" if the line contains "to be confirmed" anywhere in it.  The Neg. L-B version will only avoid changing "confirmed" if it is immediately preceded by "to be ".   A negative look behind isn't just an "AND NOT" boolean.

Comment: @cas I know, but without more info about the actual data and the task at hand, developing something better with `sed` is challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
sed '/NO_ID/ s/confirmed/to be confirmed/' stats.txt
#          ^
```

No comma here